# ROS Answers SE migration: Use of entropy

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!

I am studying slam in a real indoor environment using a Pionner robot and a hokuyo laser. After getting a map i can see if the data association is correct or not but i would like to compare analitically the whole process. Gmapping has a publisher with the entropy over the robot pose. Does anyone do anything with the entropy? I´m trying to study the values of the entropy but it use to be constant.

In case i not use the entropy, is there an easy way to get values of the uncertainty of the position?

Thanks in advance
Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139026/use-of-entropy/) by [Josejgarcia](https://answers.ros.org/users/13191/josejgarcia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the entropy over the pose is computed in a reasonable way: https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/e8a121619fdb744f151a81fae9ab7325a5faa399/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp#L519

Is it not giving reasonable values? You can try using slam_gmapping from source and adding publishers for different kinds of uncertainty (try mean square error if you don't like entropy).

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arahp](https://answers.ros.org/users/46852/arahp/) on 2020-01-14**:
What you say is true, but I think there is another question: it seems that the entropy calculated in Gmapping has not been used? It really confused me.

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2023-04-24**:
@jbinney Could you please explain what is meant by "adding publishers for different kinds of uncertainty (try mean square error if you don't like entropy)"? So instead of the line `entropy += it->weight/weight_total * log(it->weight/weight_total);` we compute the mean square error of the weights?